# How to add an ellipsis to contents(including line breaks) of a div with max-height and overflow: hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add an ellipsis at the end of contents with line breaks if it overflows a div with max-height and overflow: hidden.

I have tried to do, but the problem with my approach is if there are two line breaks only one will be shown in the output. This is this the fiddle link [https://jsfiddle.net/AkshayaKT/qg8yurt5/](http://jsfiddle.net/AkshayaKT/qg8yurt5/)

```js
var ellipsesText = "...";

$( '.card-content' ).each (function () {

    var content    = $( this ).html(),
        divheight  = $( this ).height(),
        lineheight = $( this ).css( 'line-height' ).replace( "px", "" ),
        lines      = Math.round( divheight / parseInt( lineheight ) ),
        eachLines  = content.split( /<br>/ );

    if ( lines >= 3 ) {
    
        var replaceTxt = "";
        
        $.each( eachLines, function( index, item ) {
        
            if ( index <= 2 ) {
                if ( item == "" ) {
                    replaceTxt = replaceTxt + '<br>';
                } else {
                    replaceTxt = replaceTxt + item;
                }
            }
            
        } );
        
        replaceTxt = replaceTxt + ellipsesText;
        
        $( this ).html( replaceTxt );
        
    }
    
} );
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-content {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
  max-height: 63px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-content">What is Lorem Ipsum?<br><br><br><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</div>
<div class="card-content">What is Lorem Ipsum?<br><br>hi</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` removes the thing that it splits on and adds everything in between to an array, therefore it will remove your original `<br>`'s. I see you're trying to add them back in when the `item` (i.e. line content) is empty, but you're not adding them back in when it's not empty.

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qg8yurt5/6/

```js
var ellipsesText = "...";
$('.card-content').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).html(),
    divheight = $(this).height(),
    lineheight = $(this).css('line-height').replace("px", ""),
    lines = Math.round(divheight / parseInt(lineheight)),
    eachLines = content.split(/<br>/);

  if (lines >= 3) {
    var replaceTxt = "";
    $.each(eachLines, function(index, item) {
      if (index <= 2) {
        replaceTxt = replaceTxt + item;
        if (index < 2) {
          replaceTxt = replaceTxt + '<br>';
        }
      }
    })
    replaceTxt = replaceTxt + ellipsesText;
    $(this).html(replaceTxt);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-content {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
  max-height: 63px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-content">What is Lorem Ipsum?
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</div>
<div class="card-content">What is Lorem Ipsum?
  <br>
  <br>hi</div>
<div class="card-content">No matter what you do.<br>I work just fine<br>And will cut off after 3 lines, and put ellipses on the 3rd line >>> <br>You can't see me</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, the OP's code behaves differently when `<br>` on their own lines vs crammed onto one line.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when `<br>` on their own lines" but my fix should now have the desired behaviour (multiple `<br>`s are still shown, and the ellipses are added on the same line as the last line (line 3)). Run the code snippet above and you'll see it works just fine :-)

Comment: Your code works regardless of how the `<br>` are placed in the markup.I had commented before you had updated your answer with code. Using the OP's original code, if the `<br>` were placed on different lines like you have done in your example, you would get different results, [result one](http://jsfiddle.net/AkshayaKT/qg8yurt5/) vs [result two](http://jsfiddle.net/qg8yurt5/7/). This does not happen with your code. I will remove my comment shortly.

Comment: @LaurensSwart Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @hungerstar Yes the issue you have put forward is a bit concerning. Nice catch. Thank you.